# Click - Dynamic Defaults for Prompts based on other options

Tags: python, python-click

I'm using [Click](http://click.pocoo.org) to build a CLI interface. Click offers [dynamic defaults for prompts](http://click.pocoo.org/6/options/#dynamic-defaults-for-prompts), which is great. Also [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45870325/7311767) gives some insights on how to implement dynamic defaults using a custom click-class and thus provide more flexible options when evaluating the default value.

What I'm trying to do now is to have dynamic defaults based on another provided click option, e.g.

```
python mymodule --param1 something --param2 somethingelse
```

Now if `param2` is empty I want to try to get a dynamic default based on the provided `param1` input, e.g.:

```
@click.command()
@click.option('--param1', prompt=True)
@click.option('--param2', prompt=True, default=lambda: myfunct(param1))
def cmd(param1, param2):
    pass

myfunct(param1:str=None):
    param2 = None
    #get param2 based on param1 input
    return param2
```

Any ideas on what would be the best way to get that done?
And is it guaranteed that `param1` is evaluated (and prompted for) before `param2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extending the [example you referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45870325/7311767) the desired functionality can be done like:

###Custom Class:

```
import click

class OptionPromptNull(click.Option):
    _value_key = '_default_val'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.default_option = kwargs.pop('default_option', None)
        super(OptionPromptNull, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_default(self, ctx, **kwargs):
        if not hasattr(self, self._value_key):
            if self.default_option is None:
                default = super(OptionPromptNull, self).get_default(ctx, **kwargs)
            else:
                arg = ctx.params[self.default_option]
                default = self.type_cast_value(ctx, self.default(arg))
            setattr(self, self._value_key, default)
        return getattr(self, self._value_key)

    def prompt_for_value(self, ctx):
        default = self.get_default(ctx)

        # only prompt if the default value is None
        if default is None:
            return super(OptionPromptNull, self).prompt_for_value(ctx)

        return default
```

###Using the Custom Class:

To use the custom class you need to pass three parameters to the `click.option` decorator like:

```
@click.option('--param3', cls=OptionPromptNull, default_option='param1',
              default=lambda x: get_a_value(x), prompt="Enter Param3")
```

- `cls` need to reference the custom class.
- `default_option` needs to specify which option will be passed to the `default` callable.
- `default` specifies the callable used to get the default.

###How does this work?

This works because `click` is a well designed OO framework.  The `@click.option()` decorator usually instantiates a `click.Option` object but allows this behavior to be over ridden with the `cls` parameter.  So it is a relatively easy matter to inherit from `click.Option` in our own class and over ride desired methods.

In this case we over ride the `click.Option.get_default()` and the `click.Option.prompt_for_value()` methods.  In `prompt_for_value()` we only prompt if the default is `None`.  And then in `get_default()` we call the `default` function passing the desired (previously entered) param.

And to clarify one part of the question, the options are evaluated first: in the order they were passed on the command line, and second: in the order they were declared for those that were not passed on the command line.

###Test Code:

```
@click.command()
@click.option('--param1', prompt="Enter Param1")
@click.option('--param2', cls=OptionPromptNull,
              default=lambda: get_value_none(), prompt="Enter Param2")
@click.option('--param3', cls=OptionPromptNull, default_option='param1',
              default=lambda x: get_a_value(x), prompt="Enter Param3")
def cli(param1, param2, param3):
    click.echo("param1: '{}'".format(param1))
    click.echo("param2: '{}'".format(param2))
    click.echo("param3: '{}'".format(param3))


def get_value_none():
    return None

def get_a_value(val):
    return val

if __name__ == "__main__":
    commands = (
        r'',
        r'--param3 5',
        '--help',
    )

    import sys, time

    time.sleep(1)
    print('Click Version: {}'.format(click.__version__))
    print('Python Version: {}'.format(sys.version))
    for cmd in commands:
        try:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print('-----------')
            print('> ' + cmd)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            cli(cmd.split())

        except BaseException as exc:
            if str(exc) != '0' and \
                    not isinstance(exc, (click.ClickException, SystemExit)):
                raise
```

###Results:

```
Click Version: 6.7
Python Version: 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
-----------
> 
Enter Param1: 3
Enter Param2: 4
param1: '3'
param2: '4'
param3: '3'
-----------
> --param3 5
Enter Param1: 3
Enter Param2: 4
param1: '3'
param2: '4'
param3: '5'
-----------
> --help
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS]

Options:
  --param1 TEXT
  --param2 TEXT
  --param3 TEXT
  --help         Show this message and exit.
```

Comment: This works up through click 7.1.2 but fails with click 8.0.0: `TypeError: get_default() got an unexpected keyword argument 'call'`. The signature of `get_default` changes to `def get_default(self, ctx, call: bool = True):`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is considered best practice, but another way to achieve the same effect is to use `click.get_current_context()` as part of a function that computes the default value:

```
@click.command()
@click.option(
    "--param1",
    type=str,
    prompt="First parameter",
)
@click.option(
    "--param2",
    type=str,
    prompt="Second parameter",
    default=lambda: myfunct(click.get_current_context().params.get("param1", None)),
)
def cmd(param1, param2):
    pass
```