# sphinx: document data in python without displaying the data

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx

i know i can [document (module) constants in sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#directive-autofunction) with either

```
#: a tuple of primes
primes = (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17)
```

or

```
primes =  (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17)
"""a tuple of primes"""
```

which will then appear in the sphinx generated documentation; i.e. it will look something like this:

> `somemodule.primes`
>
> `= (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17)`
>
> *a tuple of primes*

but what if the data is a very long list? then i would like to be able to have a docstring in the documentation but not have the actual data itself in the doc.

this is what i would like to have in the doc:

> `somemodule.primes`
>
> *a tuple of primes*

is there a way i can achieve this?

---

for completeness:

i ran `sphinx-quickstart` and enabled autodoc:

```
autodoc: automatically insert docstrings from modules (y/n) [n]: y
```

the only thing i have added to `index.rst` is:

```
``somemodule``
**************

.. automodule:: somemodule
    :members:
```

and `somemodule.py` contains this:

```
#: a tuple of primes
primes = (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17)
```

then i adapted `sys.path` in `conf.py` such that `somemodule.py` is in that path.

Comment: I'm not a sphinx expert, but I don't think sphinx is directly responsible for this - you're likely using the autodoc extension to generate your documentation, correct?

Comment: yes, the extension `sphinx.ext.autodoc` is enabled; and i use `.. automodule::` for said module.

Comment: The [`autodata`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#directive-autodata) directive accepts an `:annotation:` option that lets you hide the constant's value. I don't know if `automodule` respects that setting if you set it in [`autodoc_default_options`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_default_options`) (and if it does, it'll then apply to *all* constants), but perhaps that's worth a try.

Comment: i am looking into `autodata` with mixed success so far. if i only have an annotation (and no docstring) i seem to get the annotation plus the  `tuple` docstring: `tuple() -> empty tuple tuple(iterable) -> tuple initialized from iterable’s items

    If the argument is a tuple, the return value is the same object.
`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just in case somebody ends up here. To hide the contents of a variable use the [meta info list field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45870325/2844674).

```
Example:

primes = (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17)
"""A tuple of primes.

   :meta hide-value:
"""
```

Comment: great! thanks! haven't tested it yet but it looks as if ti was made for the job!

Comment: In my hands, this only worked if I omitted whitespace before the directive - as shown above, the `:meta hide-value:` didn't work, but if I removed the leading spaces between the newline and `:meta` then it worked fine.  Using sphinx 3.5.4 here.

Comment: This also gets picked up from `#:` comments before the variable.

Comment: This only works with Sphinx 3.5.0 and newer. Ubuntu 18.04 comes with 1.6 and 20.04 comes with 1.8, so there you're out of luck with the distributed sphinx. You can of course install newer sphinx via pip, but that may break other parts of your system.

Comment: @MartinPecka you are not stuck with distro version, just create a virtual environment with venv (or whatever other venv tool you like) and install the latest version of all packages.

Comment: @JuanPi Not in case I need the docs to be built by a buildfarm over which I have no control... Using distribution versions of packages is a must if you want to build publicly distributable packages via official distro channels.

Comment: @MartinPecka that scenario has nothing to do with your previous comment. There are always constrained scenarios. Anyways publicly distributing packages can be done with way less restrictive scenarios than the one you describe. And, documentation building is more on the side of development, so, in the worst case, build the docs locally with any sphinx you need and upload the tar.gz or zip file to the online service to be added to the package

Comment: Also, any official distribution of python will have venv with it and you can the create virtual env in within the distro, there are very few cases in which you do not have that power. Read up on venv

Answer (score 1):

i ended not having any documentation for `somemodule.primes` in `somemodule.py` (which makes sphinx ignore it) and putting a manual documentation into `index.rst`

```
``somemodule``
**************

.. automodule:: somemodule
    :members:

.. py:data:: somemodule.primes

    a tuple of primes
```

so far i found no way doing something similar directly in `somemodule.py`.